# Getting 'extraneous key is not permitted' for keys that are defined in CDK documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I am trying to setup a `DefaultCacheBehaviorProperty` in my Cloudformation stack from my CDK. Following the official documentation here: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudfront.CfnDistribution.DefaultCacheBehaviorProperty.html)

Writing the code like this:

```
const defaultCacheBehaviour: CfnDistribution.DefaultCacheBehaviorProperty = {
            compress: true,
            viewerProtocolPolicy: "redirect-to-https",
            targetOriginId: "api-gw-origin",
            forwardedValues: {
                queryString: true
            },
            lambdaFunctionAssociations: [
                {
                    eventType: LambdaEdgeEventType.VIEWER_REQUEST,
                    lambdaFunctionArn: this.getLambdaEdgeArnString(CHECK_AUTH_LAMBDA_EDGE_ARN_PARAM_NAME)
                }
            ],
            defaultTtl: 0,
            minTtl: 0,
            maxTtl: 0
        }

cloudfrontDistribution.distribution.addPropertyOverride("DistributionConfig.DefaultCacheBehavior",
            defaultCacheBehaviour
        );
```

Now when deploying in Cloudformation, I'm getting the error:

```
Properties validation failed for resource CloudfrontDistributionECD with message:
#/DistributionConfig/DefaultCacheBehavior: extraneous key [minTtl] is not permitted
#/DistributionConfig/DefaultCacheBehavior: extraneous key [compress] is not permitted
#/DistributionConfig/DefaultCacheBehavior: extraneous key [maxTtl] is not permitted
#/DistributionConfig/DefaultCacheBehavior: extraneous key [viewerProtocolPolicy] is not permitted
#/DistributionConfig/DefaultCacheBehavior: extraneous key [forwardedValues] is not permitted
#/DistributionConfig/DefaultCacheBehavior: extraneous key [lambdaFunctionAssociations] is not permitted
#/DistributionConfig/DefaultCacheBehavior: extraneous key [defaultTtl] is not permitted
#/DistributionConfig/DefaultCacheBehavior: extraneous key [targetOriginId] is not permitted
```

Seems like the documentation is outdated? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of fields that you are trying to set are deprecated. If you look at the field description in the documentation that you linked, it's written there.

Addition: Why do you go with L1 construct? You could more easily go with L2 construct [Distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudfront.Distribution.html) to create your CloudFront distribution and set default behavior property in it.

In addition to that, and also as recommended in the documentation, you should use cachePolicy to define you caching behaviours, like min, max, default ttl